# Modifying underlying data structure of std::vector doesn't change its size

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, java-native-interface

I am using `std::vector` in a class bridging JNI entry point with a new C++ library.

Because there are a lot of JNI calls involving `jbyteArray`'s, I've written simple conversion functions:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> Jni::Types::vectorForJarray(jbyteArray a) {
    auto env = Jni::getEnv();
    auto len = env->GetArrayLength(a);
    std::vector<uint8_t> result;
    result.reserve(static_cast<unsigned int>(len));
    env->GetByteArrayRegion (a, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(result.data()));
    return result;
}
```

and

```
jbyteArray Jni::Types::JarrayForVector(std::vector<uint8_t> v) {
    auto env = Jni::getEnv();
    auto array = env->NewByteArray(v.size());
    if (env->GetArrayLength(array) != v.size()) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(array);
        array = env->NewByteArray(v.size());
    }
    void* temp = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(array, 0);
    memcpy(temp, v.data(), v.size());
    env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(array, temp, 0);
    return array;
}
```

**The problem**

If I modify the `vector` via its `data()` method, its length (got via `size()`) will stay at 0. Have you any ideas how to make the vector show the correct size? I will note, that this function is called a *lot of* times, so performance is quite important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course the vector's size will not increase. Think about it.

You are using GetByteArrayRegion to copy data directly to the vector's underlying buffer. How do you expect it's 'size' member to change.

To fix this I would set the size of the vector as I create it using it's [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

```
std::vector<uint8_t> result(static_cast<unsigned int>(len), 0);
```

This will create the vector and fill it with len number of elements, each being a copy of the second parameter which in this case is 0.

Now the size of the vector is what you want it to be so copying data directly into it using GetByteArrayRegion should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
memcpy(temp, v.data(), v.size());
```

This line does not change the size property of the std::vector.

It just 
"Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage. The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a valid range, even if the container is empty." 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Instead,

```
result.reserve(static_cast<unsigned int>(len));
```

can be changed to

```
result.resize(static_cast<unsigned int>(len));
```

Comment: You can't `reinterpret_cast ` a `std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator` into a jbyte*. That's why I used `data()`.

Comment: I return a `jbyteArray` in this function, the vector is not supposed to change here.